# Cannot run python server on my local

Tags: python, pydev

When i run python manage.py runserver, i get following error

```
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 5678
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/../../../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 488, in start_client
    s.connect((host, port))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

my manage.py

```
import os
import sys
import pymysql

# Uncomment if you want to debug using pydevd
if (os.environ.get('LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT', '')):
  import pydevd
  pydevd.settrace(stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True, suspend=False)
```